# duplicate qqnorm

Tags: regression, normality-assumption, qq-plot

I am trying to duplicate the qqnorm plot here

```
x=  c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
y = c(10,45,39,50,77,20,28,14,25,23,33)
length(x)
length(y)
l = lm(x~y)
plot(l) #### PRESS ENTER 3 times to see the QQNORM plot below
```

[image]

How would you manually reproduce that with the standardized residuals from the regression model

```
StbdardizedRediduals = rstandard(l)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicating" it?

Comment: If you find the answer to the duplicate a little cryptic, then please look at some of the other related threads by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=plotting+points+probability+plot).

Comment: @whuber   can you provide a link??  The reason I posted is beacuase I searched and did  NOT find anything

Comment: I already provided two links. Click on the link beneath the message "This question already has an answer here" to visit the duplicate.  Click on the link in my comment to carry out a suitable search.